# Can a Message Driven Bean handle JMS Messages synchronously?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb, jms

An MDB is passed a message by invoking onMessage() method by the Java EE container.

This allows for asynchronous consumption of messages where the client (the MDB) does not need to call receive on a Topic or Queue rather the container/provider will deliver the message automatically to it.

Is there anyway we can use the MDB for synchronous consumption of messages?
Can we create a connection for example in PostConstruct method or within the onMessage method on some destination and call receive()?

If this upper case is a possibility then what can we deduce from it? That is MDB can handle messages both synchronously and asynchronously?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you know: [oracle tutorial to mdbs](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gipko.html)

As soon as the bean has been triggered, it can use the JMS-Interface on any Resource as you want. You can receive further messages, you can put further messages on the topic, and so on.

But you depend on being initially triggered by a message on the topic or queue, the MDB is defined on.
If you want to trigger the MDB as soon as the message is put into the queue, why not call onMessage or something similar on the Bean directly?

```
If this upper case is a possibility then what can we deduce from
it? That is MDB can handle messages both synchronously and asynchronously?
```

The MDB initially is triggered asynchronously. That is the main feature of an MDB. What it does afterwards as an almost normal bean has no influence on that.

Further more: 
The question whether the MDB is used synchronously or asynchronously depends on the underlying messaging framework. In EJB it is defined asynchronously. The MDB normally is called in another thread than the client which originally sent the message. mockrunner-jms for instance is an in memory messaging framework, that can be used when trying to test messaging, can be configured, to call the consumers synchronously in the same thread.